biblatex not printing reference list
The command \printbibliography doesn't output the list of references in my .bib file. Here is a minimum working example:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=authoryear, style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{referencias}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Primera}
Esto es relleno, \cite{waveKernel}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}

The results returned by the build process are:

Citation 'waveKernel' is undefined.
Empty bibliography.
There were undefined references.

Funny thing is that I get the intended results when following this alternative approach:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Primera}
Esto es relleno, \cite{waveKernel}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{referencias.bib}

\end{document}

Of course, I can't use it because is not the style that I should use in my report. I don't know what am I doing wrong, I ran bibtex, then latex twice, I added the .bib extension, remove it, every single thing gives the same results. My setup is:

TexLive: TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023/Debian)
Bibtex: Version 0.99d


Biber and BibTeX are different programs that roughly do a similar thing. With biblatex you should run Biber. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains what the programs do. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 explains how you can configure your editor to run Biber.

Note that citestyle=authoryear, style=apa, is a bit confusing since style=apa, sets both bibstyle and citestyle to apa, so citestyle=authoryear, does nothing. For full APA style, better use just style=apa,

David already said it in his answer, but the usage of file extensions is exactly the other way round. \addbibresource needs the .bib, so it should be \addbibresource{referencias.bib}, whereas \bibliography should not have the .bib so it should be \bibliography{referencias}.

You say you ran bibtex but if you run pdflatex you get the clear message
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                file
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

so you need to run biber not bibtex as you are using biblatex.
If you run biber you get the message
INFO - This is Biber 2.20
INFO - Logfile is 'file.blg'
INFO - Reading 'file.bcf'
INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex file 'referencias' for section 0
ERROR - Cannot find 'referencias'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1

as it is looking for a file referencias  so instead specify referencias.bib with the .bib extension.
\addbibresource{referencias.bib}

a bibliography is generated and then re-running pdflatex produces the warning
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please rerun LaTeX.
(biblatex)                Page breaks have changed.

so running pdflatex again  produces no warnings and

You provided no bib file so I used referencias.bib
@misc {waveKernel,
title={wibble},
author={duck},
year={2024}
}


Thanks for this info!
